# Can we return a String in a PHP function?

Tags: php, function, return-value

I would like to return a string from a PHP function. I have two methods to do the same and both the methods work. I've seen lots of examples similar to Method 2 but none similar to Method 1.

Is there any caveat to using Method 1?

**Method 1:**

```
<?php
    function test() {
        if (some condition)
            return 'Some Text';
        }
        else {
            return 'Some Other Text';
        }
    }
    if (test() === 'Some Text') {
        // Do Something
    }
?>
```

**Method 2:**

```
<?php
    function test() {

        if (some condition)
            $text = 'Some Text';
        }
        else {
            $text = 'Some Other Text';
        }
        return $text;
    }

    if (test() === 'Some Text') {
        // Do Something
    }
?>
```

Comment: both are totally fine. i prefer 1, creating $text serves no purpose in method 2

Comment: First is _return early_ second is _return once_, it's personal preference.

Comment: As long as you don't mix the two styles too much within the same project - or even worse function - either is fine.

Comment: Why would this be downvoted? The question is written very clear with good examples.

Comment: no my vote, but it is a question about opinion.

Comment: @smith It is not. He asks if there is downside in using the first method. He doesn't know that it is just a matter of opinion at the time of asking

Comment: @smith I don't think this is a question about opinion. As pointed out in the accepted answer, Method 1 has multiple return statements and might lead to regression if it's not properly executed. Method 2 doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Refer to our sister site, SoftEng.SE: [Should I return from a function early or use an if statement?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/18454/120809) which is apparently also closed, since it's opinion-based after all.

Comment: @AndrewT. In that question the asker already knows there is no difference and asks what is the best style. In the question OP does clearly not know that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are both equivalent in terms of functionality.

The 2nd form requires an extra temporary variable.  That is a micro-optimization that should not be important to you but it does exist.

The concern with Method1 is that you have multiple places where the function can exit/return, and an omission or modification has a greater chance of causing a regression that you might not find if you don't have good unit test coverage or just plain regression testing.

It also allows you to return entirely different things, which can be convoluted and hard to understand for people who have to modify the code at a later time.

Frequently there are functions that have additional conditions (if-then-elseif etc) where things are not as clear cut, and for that reason, form 2 is sometimes favored.  That usually looks a bit different, because it is dependent on setting a default initialization value:

```
function test() {
    $text = 'Default value';

    if (some condition)
        $text = 'Some Text';
    } elseif (some other condition) {
        $text = 'Some Other Text';
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Comment: Using multiple return and causing regression is a very valid point. I'll stick to Method 2. Thanks.